# WSO2 EMM blacklist not working

Tags: android, wso2-iot

I'm not able to create a blacklist of applications in the policy. (Application Restriction)
There is communication between Android and WSO2 server. WSO2 Agent is installed in BYOD.
I used the exact name of the application for example `com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator`

We only want to achieve that users don't see the play Store and others stores to add applications.

Blacklist applications prevents you from using the applications defined in the policy. For Android operation systems before Lollipop, when a blacklisted application is clicked a screen is displayed to prevent you from using the app. For the Lollipop Android operating systems and after, the blacklisted apps will be hidden. Blacklisting can be used on both BYOD and COPE devices.

[image]

Comment: What EMM version are you using?

Comment: Could you able to see the policy bundle operation in operation bar.What was the status of the operation.Still is it in pending status or its in completed status.

Comment: I'm running the latest version of the WSO2 IoT sever. The policy is synced and not pending. Thanks

Comment: Hi Frederik,
For BYOD in Android you have to use Android for work(work profiles) if you need whitelisting and blacklisting, however there has been some bugs in the agent side and has been fixed recently[1] therefore, for the agent, please use the master branch[2].
Recommendation for COPE is to use device owner concept[3] 

[1]. https://github.com/wso2/product-iots/issues/1432
[2]. https://github.com/wso2/cdmf-agent-android
[3]. https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Device+Ownership+Application